# How can I move an image and scale or resize it in the same activity

Tags: android, android-studio, drag-and-drop, gesture, image-scaling

how's it going?  I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to move an image and resize it within the same activity? I setup a listener to move the image and that works well. The commented out code was used to resize the image and that worked well also. But I am struggling to figure out how to implement some kind of GestureDetector or something similar to do both. Here is the code I have so far:

````
    private static final String TAG = "CreateOutfitActivity";

    Context mContext;

    ImageView bodyImage, outfitOne, close;
    Button saveButton;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Spinner spinner;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    String currentUserID;
    DatabaseReference privateUserReference;
    String CategoryKey;

    List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<>();
    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;

    ViewGroup rootLayout;
    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_outfits);
        mContext = CreateOutfitActivity.this;

        deployWidgets();
        setupRecyclerView();
        setupFirebase();
        setupSpinner();

    }

    private void deployWidgets(){
        bodyImage = findViewById(R.id.bodyimage);
        outfitOne = findViewById(R.id.image_view_one);
        close = findViewById(R.id.close);
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.outfit_recycler_view);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        outfitOne.bringToFront();

        rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.view_root);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1000, 1000);
        outfitOne.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        outfitOne.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    }

    private void setupRecyclerView(){
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    }

    private void setupFirebase(){
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        privateUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("private_user");
    }

    private void setupSpinner(){
        spinnerArray.add("Cutouts");
        spinnerArray.add("All Items");
        spinnerArray.add("Accessories");
        spinnerArray.add("Athletic");
        spinnerArray.add("Casual");
        spinnerArray.add("Dresses");
        spinnerArray.add("Jackets");
        spinnerArray.add("Jewelery");
        spinnerArray.add("Other");
        spinnerArray.add("Pants");
        spinnerArray.add("Purses");
        spinnerArray.add("Shirts");
        spinnerArray.add("Shoes");
        spinnerArray.add("Shorts");
        spinnerArray.add("Suits");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().toLowerCase();
                CategoryKey = text;
                if (position == 1){
                    CategoryKey = text.replace("All Items", "all_items");
                }
//                if (text.equals("All Items")){
//
//                }
                queryFirebaseToDisplayCategory(CategoryKey);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void queryFirebaseToDisplayCategory(String CategoryKey){

        Query query = privateUserReference.child(currentUserID).child(CategoryKey).orderByKey();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Category> firebaseRecyclerOptions =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>().setQuery(query, Category.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, OutfitViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, OutfitViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OutfitViewHolder outfitViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Category category) {

                        String PostKey = getRef(i).getKey();

                        Picasso.get().load(category.getFile_uri()).into(outfitViewHolder.recyclerImage);
                        outfitViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                privateUserReference.child(currentUserID).child(CategoryKey).child(PostKey)
                                        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        String fileURI = dataSnapshot.child("file_uri").getValue().toString();
                                        displayRecyclerImage(fileURI);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public OutfitViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_outfit_item_view, parent, false);
                        return new OutfitViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    private void displayRecyclerImage(String fileURI){
        if (fileURI != null){
            Picasso.get().load(fileURI).into(outfitOne);
        }
    }

    public class OutfitViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView = itemView;
        ImageView recyclerImage;

        public OutfitViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            recyclerImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.outfit_recycler_image);
        }
    }

    private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
            final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
                    _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                    _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = -0;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = -0;
                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
            }
            rootLayout.invalidate();
            return true;
        }

    }

    private class MySimpleOnScaleGestureListener
            extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener{

        ImageView viewMyImage;

        float factor;

        public MySimpleOnScaleGestureListener(ImageView iv) {
            super();
            viewMyImage = iv;
            factor = 1.0f;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor() - 1;
            factor += scaleFactor;
            viewMyImage.setScaleX(factor);
            viewMyImage.setScaleY(factor);
            return true;
            //return super.onScale(detector);
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

For moving ImageView or whatever in the Activity you could use Animations like below.
 to Move the Image from Bottom to Top with Transparency animation, first you have to create a folder named (animation) inside RES folder and then create an Animation resource file (Right click on the created Animation Folder ) and past this code inside.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:fromYDelta="100%"
     android:duration="100"
     android:repeatCount="0" />
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:duration="100"
  android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```

and don't forget to call the animation inside your Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Animation anim;
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        ImageView YourImage = findViewById(R.id.Image);
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.gotop );
        YourImage.startAnimation( anim );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `MySimpleOnScaleGestureListener`:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor() - 1;
            factor += scaleFactor;

            // scale
            viewMyImage.animate().scaleX(scaleFactor);
            viewMyImage.animate().scaleY(scaleFactor);

            // move
            view.animate().translationX(distance);
            view.animate().translationY(distance);

            return true;
            //return super.onScale(detector);
        }
```

Comment: What is `distance`?